# Click handler for Button with SVG

Tags: jquery, svg

I have a button with an SVG as its logo:

```
<div id="measure-representation">
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-state="audio">Audio
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg" height="80px" data-state="audio">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#80ff00" opacity="1"></circle>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

The button has `data-state="audio"`, and because I am troubleshooting, the SVG does as well (not sure if SVG supports data-state).   I am trying to allow the user to click the button and then get the `data-state` from it, and do other things using that info.   The problem is if I click directly on the SVG within the button, it thinks I am clicking on the SVG, and not the button.  ( i have verified this by forcing the height and width attrivutes of the SVG, and clicking on the surrounding portion of the button.  I get the `data-state` when I click the button, but I get nothing when I click the SVG.

I think this might be the selector code I am using (in backbone), but I alos think it might be solved with how I structure the HTMl of the button and the SVG, not sure which way is better convention, or possible.

Backbone view and click handler:

```
el : $("#measure-representation"), // Specifies the DOM element which this view handles

events : {
  "click .btn" : "cycle",  //Trying to differentiate and/or 
  "click .svg" : "cycle"   //capture the btn click or the SVG click
},
....
cycle: function(button) {
  //This works if I click the button
  var buttonNewState = $(button.target).data('state');
  //Tried different ways to select the SVG from the JQuery event 
  var svgNewState = ....
},
```

The paramater `button` in the `cycle` function is a JQuery event Object, so `$(button.target)[0]` is returning the HTML of what I am clicking on.   It returns the HTML of the button (which includes the SVG and the paths), or it is the SVG (and includes the paths), or it is the path I click on.   Would I have to put the `data-state` on every element in the button? or what better selector should I use to bubble up to get the `data-state` of the button?

The SVG's are more than just a circle, so font-awesome cant be substituted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the data attribute from the button, bind the event to the button and use `e.currentTarget`:

```
events : {
  "click .btn" : "cycle",  //Trying to differentiate and/or   
},
....
cycle: function(e) {
  //This works if I click the button
  var buttonNewState = $(e.currentTarget).data('state');

},
```

This allows the event to bubble up to the element that you've bound it to which can be accessed via `e.currentTarget`. `e.target` will still refer to the exact element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
events : {
  "click .btn" : "cycle",  //Trying to differentiate and/or 
  "click .svg" : "cycle"   //capture the btn click or the SVG click
},
....
cycle: function(e) {
  //This works if I click the button
  var audio;
  if($(e.target).is('button'))
    audio = $(e.targe).data('state');
  else
    audio = $(e.targe).closest('button').data('state');     
},
```